# AngularJS: How to avoid copying reference from one scope to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have following code where i need to create a single instance which have been updated and saved without any change on the previous scope.

```
console.log("Trying to save playlist");
                    console.log($rootScope.selectedSounds);
                    $scope.playlistInstance = $rootScope.selectedSounds;
                    var preparedSoundsForSave = [];
                    angular.forEach($scope.playlistInstance, function (selectedSound, key){
                      console.log("Sound to playlist is following:");
                      console.log(selectedSound);
                      var selectedSoundInstance = selectedSound;
                      selectedSoundInstance.state = 0;
                      delete selectedSoundInstance.mediaInstance ;
                      preparedSoundsForSave.push(selectedSoundInstance);
                    });
                    // Create the new object which has been saved
                    $scope.playlist.name = $scope.playlistName;
                    $scope.playlist.tracks = preparedSoundsForSave;
                    console.log($scope.playlist);
                    existingPlaylists.push($scope.playlist);
                    localStorageService.set("playlists", existingPlaylists);
                    $ionicLoading.show({
                        duration: 1000,
                        template: $translate.instant('SAVED')
                    });
                    $scope.playlistName = "";
```

So i created single instance, changed some values and saved changed array.
Problem is, that changes are automatically passed to the:

```
$rootScope.selectedSounds
```

Without any reason.

I would like to ask, how can i do it in AngularJS correctly please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: why are you storing variables on `$rootScope`? that's a major anti-pattern.

Comment: I had a some problems with storing values between between controllers during the playing media instance. I think, that using rootscope  is not pointing directly to my question?

Comment: it doesn't appear as though this is all the code in this function, and you aren't showing the expressions you are using in your HTML.  there isn't anything in the code you posted that would create the issue you are describing, but it's likely that something else is going on, especially if you felt like using `$rootScope` was the only workaround for some other issue you were having.

Comment: I found, that rootScope has no effect on this problem. I rewrote rootScope to standard scope and situation is absolutely same .

Comment: Correct, rootScope isn't the issue here, but it is an anti-pattern that gives the impression that you are not doing things "the angular way...", and that somewhere else, there is abnormal syntax creating the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript objects are passed by reference. So when you are copying the object in a different variable the reference remains the same hence any changes to any one will apply to both the object.

To create a copy with a different reference you can use

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

Or by using loadash or underscore like

```
_.extend({},oldObj)
```

Comment: the proper angular way to copy an object being `angular.copy`